# Как оформить в одну строку вывод текста со значениями % format в python

Tags: python

У меня в 2 сроки получется код

```
print("Пропусков стало:")
'{:.1%}'.format(new.isnull().sum().sum() / df.size)
```

Сейчас выводится например

```
Пропусков стало: 
0.2 %
```

А как сделать, чтобы выводилось в одну строку(например)

```
Пропусков стало: 0.2 %
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо просто не разделять один аргумент на два:

```
print("Пропусков стало: {:.1%}".format(new.isnull().sum().sum() / df.size))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print("Пропусков стало: {:.%1}".format(...))
```